# Can I override window.onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript

Now that my window.onbeforeunload process is working correctly, I don't want it to fire when the user uses the buttons I have provided:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnSaveResponses" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnSaveResponses_Click" />
   <asp:Button ID="btnFinished" runat="server" Text="Finished" onclick="btnFinshed_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
```

If the user clicks either of these, I don't want my window.onbeforeunload procedure to fire.

This is that procedure:

```
    <script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
           var element1 = document.getElementById('btnFinished');
           if (element1 != null) {
               //code to set the value variable.
               document.getElementById('btnFinished').click();
           }
           else {
               alert("element is null");
           }
           return false;
       };
</script>
```

I added these 2 functions to the bottom of the page:

```
    <script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         function setDoNotFire
         {
            var doNotFire=true;
         };
</script> 
<script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         function Fire
         {
            var doNotFire=false;
         };
</script>
```

Plus this:

```
    <body onload ="Fire()">
```

And this:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnSaveResponses" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnSaveResponses_Click"  OnClientClick ="setDoNotFire()"/>
   <asp:Button ID="btnFinished" runat="server" Text="Finished" onclick="btnFinshed_Click" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick ="setDoNotFire()"/>
```

And finally:

```
    <script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
           if (doNotFire!=true) {
               var element1 = document.getElementById('btnFinished');
               if (element1 != null) {
                   //code to set the value variable.
                   document.getElementById('btnFinished').click();
               }
               else {
                   alert("element is null");
               }
               return false;
           }
       };
</script>
```

It didn't work at all. It no longer does anything, so I am guessing it cannot find the variable doNotFire.

Comment: I don't want to see "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." when the correct buttons are clicked, only when tab or window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to override it, just make the existing one more flexible.
Declare a global variable `doNotFire =false`.
When button is clicked, swith variable to true.
In you `onBeforeUnload` code, check that `doNotFire` is false.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
doNotFire = false;
function doSomething(){
if (!doNotFire){
 ....
}
</script>
</head>
<body onbeforeunload="doSomething();">
...
 <asp:Button ID="btnSaveResponses" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="doNotFiretrue;btnSaveResponses_Click();" />
   <asp:Button ID="btnFinished" runat="server" Text="Finished" onclick="doNotFiretrue; btnFinshed_Click();" CausesValidation="False" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't think that worked. I added these 2 functions to the bottom of the page:        <script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
             function setDoNotFire
             {
                var doNotFire=true;
             };
    </script> 
    <script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
             function Fire
             {
                var doNotFire=false;
             };
    </script>

Comment: Looks good, but would not work. First, onbeforeunload is not a valid property of body.

Comment: Just modify the function or code called by onbeforeunload to check doNotFire value and it should work.